# Rails - state machine working locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

I am using the state_machine gem.  Locally, i am having no problem.  When I deploy to heroku, however, the initial state is not being set.  Rather, the state is nil.

I have a model called Schedule.  It is set so that upon creation, the state is defined as 'none'.  Here is the code:

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :none do
    ...
end
```

This always works locally.  What is strange is that it does not work when using heroku through the browser, but when i type:

```
new_schedule = Schedule.new
```

in the heroku console, it is automatically setup correctly to 'none'.

Why is it working locally and in the heroku console, but not on the actual heroku site?

Comment: What DB are you using in Heroku? We found to get state_machine working with `MYSQL`, you have to declare the `state` column an index & string, but you can't set the index in `PG`. Instead, we just set it as string & it worked

Comment: Heroku and my local machine are both using PG.  The db table column is of type string.  Any ideas?

Comment: for the schedules table, whats your schema look like.. for example, do you have a default value set in the table as well?